# Webdriver cannot locate element or xpath

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, webdriver

Trying to execute a drag and drop with selenium webdriver, I'm having problems locating what I want to select. I've tried using xpaths and id selection but I haven't seem to have got it right The following highlighted code is the item i wish to select to select.

```
<div id="availableSection" class="DndSource DndTarget DndContainer" style="text-align:center;height:700px;width:400px;font-size:1.9em;border:9px solid #ddd; padding:3em;overflow:auto; ">
<div id="1" class="dojoDndItem" style="padding:.8em;margin:auto;overflow:hidden;">Selection 1</div>
**<div id="2" class="dojoDndItem" style="padding:.8em;margin:auto;overflow:hidden;">Section 2</div>**
```

Comment: I found that I was actually doing this correctly. I found a useful way to verify that I am selecting the element by using the following code.

Comment: WebElement highlightdrag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/form/fieldset/div/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/div[2]"));
   elementHighlight(highlightdrag);

Comment: public void elementHighlight(WebElement element) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   js.executeScript(
     "arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
     element, "color: red; border: 3px solid red;");
   js.executeScript(
     "arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
     element, "");

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to get your desired element.

Below code will **locate the element having exact innerHTML/text as "section 2"**:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[.='Section 2']"));
```